# Concatenating strings in muse-project-alist

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to make my muse directory more flexible, so I save the muse base directory path in a variable, like this:

```
(setq my-muse-base-dir "d:/project/notes")

(setq muse-project-alist
      `(
    ("Home" 
     ((concat my-muse-base-dir "/muse/home")
     ;; ("d:/project/notes/muse/home"
      :default "index")
     (:base "html" :path (concat my-muse-base-dir "/html/home")))
     ;; (:base "html" :path "d:/project/notes/html/home"))
    ))
```

But when I enter muse mode, it reports error as

> let: Wrong type argument: stringp,
>   (concat my-muse-base-dir "/muse/home")

And after I change the directory setting to the full paths, as shown by commented lines, the error is gone. So I'd like to know how to set directory of muse project as concatenating of two strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `,` in your backquote expression:

```
(setq muse-project-alist
      `(
        ("Home" 
         (,(concat my-muse-base-dir "/muse/home")
          :default "index")
         (:base "html" :path ,(concat my-muse-base-dir "/html/home")))
        ))
```

See the `,`s right before the calls to `concat`.

The comma tells backquote to evaluate the following expression.  Read the [backquote info page](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) for more details.

Comment: It works, thanks :-). And could you please tell me what does the semi-colon here do?

Comment: Semi-colon (`;`)?  I don't see any.  I see colons (`:`), for those you have to read the documentation for `muse-project-alist` - found here http://mwolson.org/static/doc/muse/Options-for-Projects.html

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I mean the comma here